# My application does not compile due to duplicate class

Tags: android, gradle, build

i'm trying to parse an xlsx File in my app, so i added these 2 libraries in my build.gradle

```
implementation 'org.apache.poi:poi:3.17'
implementation 'org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:3.17'
```

but when i try to compile I find these errors

```
Duplicate class org.apache.xmlbeans.xml.stream.Location found in modules xmlbeans-2.6.0.jar (org.apache.xmlbeans:xmlbeans:2.6.0) and xmlbeans-2.6.0.jar (org.apache.xmlbeans:xmlbeans:2.6.0)
Duplicate class org.apache.xmlbeans.xml.stream.ReferenceResolver found in modules xmlbeans-2.6.0.jar (org.apache.xmlbeans:xmlbeans:2.6.0) and xmlbeans-2.6.0.jar (org.apache.xmlbeans:xmlbeans:2.6.0)
Duplicate class org.apache.xmlbeans.xml.stream.XMLEvent found in modules xmlbeans-2.6.0.jar (org.apache.xmlbeans:xmlbeans:2.6.0) and xmlbeans-2.6.0.jar (org.apache.xmlbeans:xmlbeans:2.6.0)
Duplicate class org.apache.xmlbeans.xml.stream.XMLInputStream found in modules xmlbeans-2.6.0.jar (org.apache.xmlbeans:xmlbeans:2.6.0) and xmlbeans-2.6.0.jar (org.apache.xmlbeans:xmlbeans:2.6.0)
Duplicate class org.apache.xmlbeans.xml.stream.XMLName found in modules xmlbeans-2.6.0.jar (org.apache.xmlbeans:xmlbeans:2.6.0) and xmlbeans-2.6.0.jar (org.apache.xmlbeans:xmlbeans:2.6.0)
Duplicate class org.apache.xmlbeans.xml.stream.XMLStreamException found in modules xmlbeans-2.6.0.jar (org.apache.xmlbeans:xmlbeans:2.6.0) and xmlbeans-2.6.0.jar (org.apache.xmlbeans:xmlbeans:2.6.0)
Duplicate class org.apache.xmlbeans.xml.stream.utils.NestedThrowable found in modules xmlbeans-2.6.0.jar (org.apache.xmlbeans:xmlbeans:2.6.0) and xmlbeans-2.6.0.jar (org.apache.xmlbeans:xmlbeans:2.6.0)
Duplicate class org.apache.xmlbeans.xml.stream.utils.NestedThrowable$Util found in modules xmlbeans-2.6.0.jar (org.apache.xmlbeans:xmlbeans:2.6.0) and xmlbeans-2.6.0.jar (org.apache.xmlbeans:xmlbeans:2.6.0)

Go to the documentation to learn how to Fix dependency resolution errors.
```

I have no clue on how this can happen, the class does not seems to be duplicated, I tried to clean and rebuild but no action seems to spot the clue of the error.

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

go to the library, it’s located at my place: 
`C: \ Users \ Souln \ .gradle \ caches \ modules-2 \ files-2.1 \ org.apache.xmlbeans \ xmlbeans \ 2.6.0 \ 29e80d2dd51f9dcdef8f9ffaee0d4dc1c9bbfc87;`

distribute `xmlbeans-2.6.0` to the "x" folder (for example) - duplicates are deleted when unpacking; open `xmlbeans-2.6.0` using the archive, delete everything from there and copy the files from the folder "x" here.